# Angular 2 Ahead-of-Time compiler drastically increases resource consumption

Tags: performance, angular, typescript, compilation, bundling-and-minification

`Angular 2` app written in `typescript 2`.  I'd like to get your feedback before I decide whether to open an issue on the github project.

When I use the Ahead-of-Time compiler -- `ngc` -- along with `rollup.js` to build my app, it consumes a **lot** more CPU cycles in the browser. To test this:

1. I started the browser (`Firefox 49 32bit` on `Windows 7 x64`),
2. let it sit idle for a couple of minutes,
3. loaded the app in the only open tab
4. without interacting with it at all, just recorded performance using Windows' Performance Monitor

In addition, the JS bundle (which has been minified and tree-shaken) is about 500KB *larger* than its JiT compiled counterpart.

AoT compiled bundle + `vendor.js` (made up of `core-js`, `reflect-metadata` and `zone.js`):

[image]

CPU and IO operations starting 5 seconds before I load the app, extending for 1 minute (AoT):

[image]

The app was optimized following the [directions from the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile). I've also tried bundling the AoT build with `SystemJS-builder`, and avoid `Rollup.js` altogether, but the performance differential remained.

Now checkout the same exact app using in-browser, Just-in-Time compilation. The templates and styles have been inlined and all the JS bundled into one minified file using `SystemJS-builder`'s [`buildStatic`](https://github.com/systemjs/builder#self-executing-sfx-bundles)

JiT compiled bundle is about 500KB *ligher* than the AoT tree-shaken minified bundle, even though the former includes `core-js`, `reflect-metadata` and `zone.js`!

[image]

CPU and IO operations starting 5 seconds before I load the app, extending for 1 minute (JiT):

[image]

I was so shocked by these results that I've now run this test over a dozen times. The AoT loads faster but this kind of power consumption makes it a non-starter.  Can anyone replicate this? If not, how can I find out why it's happening to my app?

`Firefox 49 32bit`, `Angular 2.0.1`, `compiler-cli 0.6.3`, `node 4.5.0`, `Windows 7 x64`